# The continuity of Injectivity radius

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Dear all,

when reading a book of M. Berger, I learned that the injectivity radius Inj(x) on a compact Riemannian manifold depends continuously on the point x.

When the manifold is complete and non-compact, Inj may not be continuous. 
For example, Inj(x) decreases to zero when x moves to the most curved point on a paraboloid. However, it could be infinity at that point.

My question is, **can we prove the continuity of Inj on a non-compact manifold under some conditions?**

(I think that the weakest condition is to assume the finiteness of Inj.)

ps. I must admit that I don't know how to prove the continuity of Inj even on a compact manifold. I think that the argument should involve the stability of ODEs (the geodesic equation and Jacobi equation). If one of you have a reference about this, could you please tell me? thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure about your paraboloid example? Take a look at Proposition 2.1.10 on Page 131 of W. Klingenberg's book _Riemannian Geometry_

Comment: You write: "Inj(x) decreases to zero when x moves to the most curved point on a paraboloid." this is not true, InjRad does not not go to zero... 

Comment: In fact, on any compact region of a smooth Riemannian manifold, you have that the injectivity radius is bounded below by a strictly positive number... (see the same reference that I gave above)

Comment: Thank you a lot!! I should ask the question earlier, it had troubled me for one month... 

Comment: It is known that if M is connected and complete, then inj is a continuous function: see for example [Lee, Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds, 2018, Prop. 10.37]. See also this related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335032/is-the-injectivity-radius-semi-continuous-on-a-non-complete-riemannian-manifol.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compactness is irrelevant; i.e if it is true for compact manifolds then the same is true for complete ones. (The same proof as in comact case works, but it is easier to do this way.)

If $R<\mathrm{InjRad}_p$ then one can construct a smooth metric on a sphere with an isometric copy of $B_R(p)$ inside.

If there is a sequence of points $x_n\to x$  such that
$$\lim\ \mathrm{InjRad}_{x_n}< \mathrm{InjRad}_x,$$
apply above consruction for $R$ slightly smaller than $\mathrm{InjRad}_x$.
You get a compact manifold with non-continuous InjRad.

If there is a sequence of points $x_n\to x$ such that 
$$\lim\ \mathrm{InjRad}_{x_n}> \mathrm{InjRad}_x$$ then apply above construction for $p=x_n$ for large enough $n$ and $R>\mathrm{InjRad}_x$.
That leads to a contradiction again.